# Autolayout: table cell with variable height and two labels

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I am stuck with a bit of an advanced Autolayout topic where I need some help of you.

I have a simple custom table cell with a label pinned on the left side, and one pinned on the right side, pretty simple:

[image]

Now, I want the left label always to be at the top left corner, one line high and scaling its width depending on the content, to a maximum of 50% of the available space (if the content is more than that, I want it to be cut off with dots):

[image]

The right label I want to always be in the top right corner, growing to the left until reaching the left label's right border. Depending on the width of the left label, the right one may become wider or thinner:

[image]

Now, in case the content doesn't fit into the right label, I want it to use several lines changing the size of the cell, but still respecting the size of the left label:

[image]

I know how to make a label automatically grow the table cell, but I have no idea how to configure the relationship between the left and the right labels correctly.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following constraints:

- A width constraint on the `leftLabel` stating that it should be less than or equal to the superview's `width / 2`. Give this constraint a priority of `1000` (absolutely required).
- A horizontal spacing constraint between the `leftLabel`'s trailing to the `rightLabel`'s leading, at a lesser priority than the above one but still required (say, `900`).
- Make the `leftLabel`'s horizontal content hugging priority `1000`.

How to do the first constraint in XIB:

Basically just `Ctrl + left click` on the `leftLabel` to the superview, add an `Equal Widths` constraint, then modify the constraint to `<=` instead of `=`. Also modify the `Multiplier`; instead of `1`, make it `1:2` or `2:1`, where 2 corresponds to the width of the superview.

Comment: Thanks! That made it! Just one thing I would like to add: I wasn't able to set the "width equality" constraint to be for a label and its subview which in my case was the content view of a table view cell. Therefore, I have simply added another UIView to my tableViewCell that has constraints to 0 on all four borders, and added the rest as you stated to this new view as superview.

Comment: Ah yes--I forgot to mention, you need to add that additional "wrapper" view because you can't directly set an equal widths constraint on the cell's `contentView`.